# How can I get video ID of previously uploaded video which is rejected as duplicate video on Youtube?

Tags: youtube-api

I have uploaded my video content to Youtube but after that I saw a "trouble" about it ,
When the same video is uploaded again to Youtube with same account,
Youtube is rejecting this video with this message “**Duplicate content**” and it doesn’t return to me a valid video (which is **duplicated**) URL but I want to find previous video URL  because User doesn’t understand why his/her video is rejected.

Finally ,

How can I get video ID of Previously uploaded video which is rejected as duplicate video on Youtube ?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate content means that Google checked their server to see whether the video already existed or not on their server. Because the same video already exists on their server, the message of duplicate content is displayed.

This means that you have to search for that very same video (and its URL) on YouTube. If you find the same video and the URL you have to use that video's URL - otherwise you have to convert that video into another format (by [video compression](http://blog.ektel.com.np/2012/04/huffman-encoder-decoder-vlsi-design-systematic-block-diagram/) or file convert e.g. MPEG to MWV or MWV to FLV etc.) so that Google's algorithm doesn't see it as a duplicate of the original video.

How to get the video id? [Here is an example](http://youtu.be/iXPYGj0_epw). The last one - iXPYGj0_epw - is your video id but to find that video first you have to search.

Comment: How to search with API?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the past uploaded video manager, which to me is always a real feat when I go to use YouTube -- it is not intuitive how to find this page, but once I did I could see the first attempt as well as the two rejected duplicates when I recently got this error.